# How to POST multiple values on form submit?

Tags: html

Im building a survey.

A question is built up as a matrix, where there are rows and columns.

You can see an illustration below:

[image]

When i submit the form, i have to save the answers for every row.

Question 1 and 2 are easy enough. All i need to know is the ID of the row, and the ID of the column, in order to save the answer. I can use the "name" attribute to save the row ID, and the "id" attribute to save the column id. This will get sent back with the POST method.

However, question #3 has one extra field, which i also need to send back, besides column ID and row ID (the text input value).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can post 4 values to the server, the column id, row id, value and the type so that if the type is radio button or checkbox the server will ignore the val field and if the type is textbox, the server will get the value from the value field. Does that help you ?!

Comment: Can you perhaps show an example of an input element that sends 4 different values back? Thanks :)

Comment: I was suggesting that you make the post with jquery ajax so that you can control the values that are being sent to the server and You can add a custom attribute to the controls and name it "type" and store the information that you want inside it so you can use it with jquery to get the value of this attribute and post it to the server using jquery ajax

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use AJAX because the survey is supposed to run on a client machine and not on a server (same origin policy). Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Just name all of it with the HTML `name` function then make the same base setup on mysqli and set the same pos's and markup everything with php...